# How to change column types in Spark SQL's(In java) DataFrame?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to convert a column data type from long to int in spark sql using java, I have seen some of example in scala and trying out but, Its not wotking

```
df.withColumn("is_open",  toInt("is_open"));
```

where do I need to change.
thanks in advance

Comment: `df.withColumn("is_open", col("is_open").cast("int"))` ?

Comment: Not working, error is showing "The method col(String) is undefined for the type" @philantrovert

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the **cast** function.

```
scala> val df = spark.range(10)
df: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Long] = [id: bigint]

scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> df.withColumn("new_col", col("id").cast("string"))
res4: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: bigint, new_col: string]
```

Comment: Not working in java, error is showing "The method col(String) is undefined for the type" @Constantine,

Comment: Can you check the spark documentation ? You can either use col or column. Please import it if not.

Comment: You should be able to use it after import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col;

Comment: yes, now error is gone by importing static function.col. But In console Info is showing CatalystSqlParser: Parsing command: int, and when we see using df.printschema(), that datatype is not converted.

Comment: This because you have to remember to update the Object: `df = df.withColumn("new_col", col("id").cast("string"))`

Comment: try this dataSet = dataSet.withColumn("new_col", dataSet.col("id").cast("string"))

Answer (score 2):

```
df = df.withColumn("is_open", df.col("is_open").cast("int"));
```

Please be aware, this cast is applying after the data is computed on previous step. If the previous step is select or something similar, it will compute into original type first, and then convert to new type on the next step. This will not solve an issue with selecting into original type.